# How do I create a random string in Free Pascal?

Tags: string, dynamic, random, freepascal

I want to write a function `GenString` that returns a random string of length `[0 .. 100]` based on a parameterized function `GenChar` that users could customize.

That is, if one user wants to generate a string of all `a`s, he could do that by passing in a function that always returns `a`, and another user could generate random alphabetic Hebrew words by passing in a custom `GenChar` function that returns random Hebrew letters.

Lemma 1: I want to write a function `GenArray` that generates an array of whatever type a passed-in function `GenThing : sometype` returns. Could this be done in Free Pascal.

Lemma 2: What I'm trying to do is port [QuickCheck](http://www.yellosoft.us/quickcheck) to Free Pascal.

Comment: That looks pretty simple: Create the `GenString` function and define the `GenChar` function prototype. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, I'm having trouble **creating the GenString function**. Could you supply example code for a GenString function?

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example. Unicode string is used since international characters is mentioned.

```
//The functions

type
  TGenChar = function: widechar;

function GenString(MaxLength: integer; GenChar: TGenChar): widestring;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  if MaxLength < 1 then
    MaxLength:= 1; //minimum length is 1
  setlength(result, random(MaxLength+1));
  for i:= 1 to length(result) do
    result[i]:= GenChar;
end;


//The usage example (remember to call randomize somewhere in your program)

var
  SampleCharSet: widestring= 'ABCxyz';

function SampleGenChar: widechar;
begin
  result:= SampleCharSet[random(length(SampleCharSet))+1];
end;

function GetRandomStringSample: widestring;
begin
  result:= GenString(100, SampleGenChar);
end;
```

Comment: Never, ever, *ever* call randomize *anywhere* other than your main unit's initialization section, or immediately after the main **begin** for console programs!

Comment: Usually, `Randomize` should only be called once at start of program, but I don't see any harm to console programs nor harm of calling it from anywhere else excluding the issue that it isn't thread safe. Could you explain more?

Comment: Randomize sometimes uses the current time to seed the internal PRNG, usually only to millisecond accuracy. If you call Randomize multiple times per program, particularly in quick succession (say you generate multiple random strings for a StringList or somesuch) you run the risk of seeding the PRNG with the same time value twice, producing identical results. Of course this wasn't your intention as GetRandomStringSample function is just a sample function.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. Since that problem can only be solved using custom function or third party library, the code should only be used for reference and not actual use as the OP wanted.

Comment: I agree with you, but the code sample is as a result slightly misleading. Consider my edit, so that the user can make his own decisions wrt randomize (if he doesn't call it, he'll get the same strings every run and will quickly google up the solution, and if he already does, then it's all good anyway). It's not *that* important but I think it should be mentioned.

Comment: @Jay, Thomas, one last thing: Could you generalize GenString to generate an array of *some type*, where *some type* is the return type of *GenThing*?

Comment: @mcandre: You can use `variant` type as the *general* type. It's like a VB variable where you can assign any type of value or be assigned to a typed variable. Type conversions will be done automatically. Will raise an exception if it can't be converted.

Comment: @Jay, I can't get it to work, because Pascal seems to think `GenArray(GenChar)` means call `GenChar` now rather than passing the function itself to `GenArray`. https://github.com/mcandre/paycheck

Comment: Either one can be used. `array of variant` would be simpler and faster since it's already in the form of an array. Using `variant` as the result type is slower because the actual array is enclosed in a variant value. Thus, requires one additional step to access an array element. If you need to add custom data to the result (e.g.: character set info), `variant` type should be used. So that the result would be an array of: 1) The array of characters; 2) Character set info.

Comment: @mcandre: Add a `@` before the function name to explicitly reference it as a function. e.g.: `GenArray(@GenChar)`. I haven't familiarize myself with `generics`, but I think it's more faster than using `variant` type.

Comment: @Jay, I'm still getting compiler errors when using `@GenChar`. Would you consider forking the code to try to fix the problem? https://github.com/mcandre/paycheck Type "make" to attempt compilation and run a test program on the code.